# if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){} is not being executed

Tags: php, html, sql-server

i am trying to figure out what mistake i am doing. When i press submit it gets me to the previous page. But my `if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){}` is not being executed. And when i check from SQL Server Profiler the query i get is Select DISTINCT date from attendance_records which is located in the previous page.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $records = sqlsrv_query($con,"select * from attendance_records where date='$_POST[date]'", array(), array("Scrollable"=>"buffered"));
       $num = sqlsrv_num_rows($records);
       if($num){

           sqlsrv_query($con, "delete from attendance_records where date= '$_POST[date]';");
           foreach ($_POST['attendance_status'] as $id=>$attendance_status){
           $student_name =$_POST['student_name'][$id];
           $roll_number =$_POST['roll_number'][$id];

           $result=sqlsrv_query($con, "insert into attendance_records(student_name,roll_number,attendance_status,date)values('$student_name','$roll_number','$attendance_status','$_POST[date]')");
                if($result){
                $update=1;
            }
        }
```

The form HTML

```
<div class="panel panel-body">
        <form action="view_all.php" method="Post">
    <H3> <div class="well text-center">Date: <?php echo $_POST['date']; ?> </div> </h3>
            <table class="table table-striped">

           <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
```

Comment: We'll need the full form. Have a hidden input `name="delete" value="true
"` and check for that instead. `<input type="submit" ...>` doesn't include it's value attribute in the POST.

Comment: It looks like you're submitting the data to `view_all.php`.  Is that the page your form processing code lives on?

Comment: <div class="panel panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel panel-heading">
        
       
         
        <div class="panel panel-body">
            <form action="view_all.php" method="Post">
       
 //some other code, Stackoverflow doesn't let me write longer than this

Comment: I am getting date value from view_all.php

Comment: @TonyChiboucas That's not true.  A submit input with a `name` and `value` attribute will appear in `$_POST` if it was the button clicked.  It won't appear if it doesn't have a valid name, or if it wasn't clicked.

Comment: if i change to <form action="change.php" method="Post"> which is the current file this time i get "Notice: Undefined index: date in C:\xampp\htdocs\Deneme4\change.php on line 10".                              Many thanks to everyone who replied to me.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a great answer for your question, but thought I'd mention that I could delete your entire database very easily with the code you've written. Think about what happens to your database query if someone submits a date of `' OR '1'='1`.

Use [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php) instead – that's what the third parameter to `sqlsrv_query()` is for. And if you're executing a statement more than once, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php).

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $date = $_POST["date"];
    $records = sqlsrv_query(
        $con,
        "SELECT * FROM attendance_records WHERE date = ?",
        array($date),
        array("Scrollable"=>"buffered")
    );
    $num = sqlsrv_num_rows($records);
    if ($num) {
        sqlsrv_query(
            $con,
            "DELETE FROM attendance_records WHERE date = ?",
            array($date)
        );
        $student_name = "";
        $roll_number = "";
        $attendance_status = "";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare(
            $con,
            "INSERT INTO attendance_records(student_name, roll_number, attendance_status, date) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)",
            array($student_name, $roll_number, $attendance_status, $date)
        );
        foreach ($_POST['attendance_status'] as $id=>$attendance_status) {
            $student_name = $_POST['student_name'][$id];
            $roll_number = $_POST['roll_number'][$id];
            if (!sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) {
                break;
            } else {
                $update = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```